# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: value on Branch.io link

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, branch.io

We followed all the default documentation for using xamarin.ios with branch.io but are getting this error whenever we open branch io link from safari which opens the IOS app

> at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ValidationUtils.ArgumentNotNull
>   (System.Object value, System.String parameterName) [0x00003] in
>   <2073514815234917a5e8f91b0b239405>:0
>
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (System.String value,
>   System.Type type, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings)
>   [0x00000] in <2073514815234917a5e8f91b0b239405>:0 at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T] (System.String value,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) [0x00000] in
>   <2073514815234917a5e8f91b0b239405>:0 at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T] (System.String value)
>   [0x00000] in <2073514815234917a5e8f91b0b239405>:0 at
>   BranchXamarinSDK.BranchUniversalObject.loadFromDictionary
>   (System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2[TKey,TValue] data) [0x00269]
>   in :0 at
>   BranchXamarinSDK.BranchUniversalObject..ctor
>   (System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2[TKey,TValue] data) [0x0000c]
>   in :0 at BranchXamarinSDK.iOS.BranchBUOSessionListener.InitCallback
>   (IOSNativeBranch.BranchUniversalObject buo,
>   IOSNativeBranch.BranchLinkProperties blp, Foundation.NSError error)
>   [0x00018] in :0 at
>   ObjCRuntime.Trampolines+SDcallbackWithBranchUniversalObject.Invoke
>   (System.IntPtr block, System.IntPtr arg0, System.IntPtr arg1,
>   System.IntPtr arg2) [0x00029] in <28041a5070c64583857f1e2a9310dbbc>:0
>   at (wrapper native-to-managed)
>   ObjCRuntime.Trampolines+SDcallbackWithBranchUniversalObject.Invoke(intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr)
>   at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr) at
>   UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr
>   principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.14.1.39/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:86
>   at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String
>   principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0000e] in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.14.1.39/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:65
>   at Drapp.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in
>   /Users/my-mac/Desktop/Projects/....../......../Main.cs:12

Any Help will be appreciated.
Thanks

**Edit: Added Code**

Im Using the code same as the integration SDK
https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/xamarin-ios

```
using BranchXamarinSDK;
using Foundation;
using GlobalToast;
using GlobalToast.Animation;
using iAd;
using Microsoft.AppCenter;
using Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics;
using Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes;
using ObjCRuntime;
using Plugin.Connectivity;
using Plugin.FirebasePushNotification;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UIKit;
using UserNotifications;

namespace MyApp
{
    // The UIApplicationDelegate for the application. This class is responsible for launching the
    // User Interface of the application, as well as listening (and optionally responding) to application events from iOS.  
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate, IBranchBUOSessionInterface
    {  

 public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
    {
        .
        .
        .
        // Debug mode - set to 'false' before releasing to production
        BranchIOS.Debug = true;
        BranchIOS.Init(Branch_key, launchOptions, this);

        return true;
    }


    // Called when the app is opened via URI scheme
    public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication application, NSUrl url, string sourceApplication, NSObject annotation)
    {
        return BranchIOS.getInstance().OpenUrl(url);
    }

    // Called when the app is opened from a Universal Link
    public override bool ContinueUserActivity(UIApplication application, NSUserActivity userActivity,
                                               UIApplicationRestorationHandler completionHandler)
    {
        return BranchIOS.getInstance().ContinueUserActivity(userActivity);
    }

    // Called when the app receives a push notification
    public override void ReceivedRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo)
    {
        BranchIOS.getInstance().HandlePushNotification(userInfo);
    }

    // Called when the Branch initialization is completed
    // Put deep-linking logic in this method
    public void InitSessionComplete(BranchUniversalObject buo, BranchLinkProperties blp)
    {

        NSObject[] keys = {
            NSObject.FromObject("+is_first_session")
        };

        NSObject[] values = { NSObject.FromObject(0) };
        if (buo.metadata.Metadata.ContainsKey("+is_first_session"))
        {
            values[0] = NSObject.FromObject(buo.metadata.Metadata["+is_first_session"]);
        }

        NSDictionary nsData = NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys(values, keys);
        NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.PostNotificationName(Branch_notification, null, nsData);
    }

    // Called when there is an error initializing Branch
    public void SessionRequestError(BranchError error)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Branch error: " + error.ErrorCode);
        Console.WriteLine(error.ErrorMessage);

        //ErrorViewController errorController = (ErrorViewController)storyboard.InstantiateViewController("ErrorScreen");

        //Window.RootViewController.PresentViewController(errorController, false, delegate
        //{
        //    errorController.SetError("Branch error: " + error.ErrorCode, error.ErrorMessage);
        //});
    }


.
.
.
.
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share your code snippet and let me know if you are using IBranchBUOSessionInterface

Comment: @KartikShandilya Check the Edit i added the code used .. its the same as the integration SDK